Should I seal the gap between framing and foundation (NOT Siding)
we recently bought a new build in the PNW. I was checking out the exterior and noticed that there are gaps where the framing meets the foundation. I know you're not supposed to seal the gap between siding and the wall, how about sealing the gap between framing and the foundation from the exterior? What products would you recommend?
Pics here:
https://imgur.com/a/klRbiLO
https://imgur.com/a/0DH30CA

Is there a closed basement? If so you want to air seal the junction of walls and foundation. If not, I don't know the tradeoffs.

@keshlam - no closed basement.

Any gaps between the top of the foundation and the underside of the stud wall should be sealed with expansion foam, at the very least to control unwanted guests gaining access to the interior.
If the area is unheated or a crawlspace, that will be enough.
If it is a living space, the entire perimeter should be sealed with expanding foam or polyurethane sealant at the intersection between the foundation wall and the framing, preferably on both the interior and exterior. This becomes part of your building envelope with the goal of controlling air infiltration.

There are exterior grade foams but I wouldn’t use them, especially in an exterior foundation context.  First, because foam degrades unless it’s protected. Second, because it can make it easier for certain insects to infest your home (like termites).  Definitely would recommend a heavy duty caulk, instead. Apply it and wipe / press it along the crack to make sure it fills the gap.
